# How to display my pygame project on a web page?

Tags: python, web, mern, figma

I am making a a personal portfolio web page where I want to display my projects but I'm not sure how to make the GUI screen appear on a webpage. I built a little puzzle game on pygame for my 1st sem project n I'd like that to appear on my webpage as an interactive surface, but I'm a little lost on how to approach this problem

I'm currently using figma and I have knowledge of MERN stack, so it'll be really helpful of you could guide me on what I'll need to use or implement

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward way is to use WebAssembly (or asm.js for older devices). Python 3.11 does not support asm.js but it has some official support for WebAssembly ( compiled with tools like Emscripten or wasi-sdk).

Pygame community edition (aka pygame-ce on pypi) can be compiled to WebAssembly too.

To ease the use of all those tools together for an application folder containing a main.py , you can install pygbag with `python3 -m pip install pygbag` and then run `python3 -m pygbag main.py`.

Then go to http://localhost:8000 or http://localhost:8000?-i (with repl) to see your program running on web !

classic helloworld : https://pygame-web.github.io/showroom/pypad_git.html#src/test_hello.py

More documentation is available on https://pygame-web.github.io